# sjPlot: set_labels() disappear

Tags: r, sjplot

I have some scripts using sjPlot that I wrote last year and now I need to run these scripts again in a new machine, but they complain that set_labels() cannot be found. I have re-installed all the packages (newest versions).

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions have been moved to the [sjlabelled-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjlabelled). Usually, this package should install along with sjPlot. If not, try re-installing sjPlot: `install.packages("sjPlot", dependencies = T)`.